# Avoid the \r when applying a QRegularExpression to a sentence

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I have extracted the following sentence :

> Very important point. It should be discussed in our next meeting.

from the following line:

> ID: 1 x: 1202 y: 2453 w: 242 h: 459 wn: 13 ln: 12 c: Very important point. It should be discussed in our next meeting.

using this QRegularExpression:

```
 regularExpression.setPattern("(?<=\\s)c:\\s?(.*)$");
```

However, the output is:

> Very important point. It should be discussed in our next meeting.\r

The presence of the \r is quite normal because the line I am working with is written in a text file (Windows 8.1 Operating System).

Do you know how to extract the sentence without having the "\r" in the resulting output ? I really have no idea.

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using a **[negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)** `[^\r\n]`:

```
regularExpression.setPattern("(?<=\\s)c:\\s?([^\r\n]*)");
                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

The `[^\r\n]*` subpattern matches zero or more characters other than `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: Hi, it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate :)

Comment: You are welcome. The negated character classes are very helpful in Qt, where lazy quantifiers are missing (you need to set laziness using a regexp `setMinimal` method or using a flag) and `.` matches any character including a newline.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the hint ;) I'll take it into account next time :)